# .Net application standard icon set

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, icons

We are developing a completely standard WPF application with a menu and toolbar. Both the menu and toolbar contain standard Windows application items like save, load, undo, redo, delete, connect etc.

We want to use the standard Windows icons, like the ones Visual Studio is using. Where can I find, buy or download the standard icon set from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default icons for Windows applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546704/default-icons-for-windows-applications)

Comment: Yes, it is. I do not know why I did not find the other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most icons are available with Visual Studio: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary`. (or wherever your Visual Studio is installed).
You should find what you are looking for here.

Regards,

Eric.

Answer (score 0):

There're alot of templates in program files/visual studio/Common folder.  Check the zip files.